# Can anyone identify this old tool?

Tags: tools, identify-a-tool

Found this in a box of junk and not sure what it is.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the other side and/or one with it open.

Comment: Definitely needs more photo angles and close ups of any writing to get a better idea of what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

Looks a bit like an older version of the sled for a chisel attachment for a sharpener wheel:

[image: sharpening wheel]

from [Wen](https://wenproducts.com/products/wen-bg4270t-10-inch-two-direction-water-cooled-wet-dry-sharpening-system?variant=39722103767074&currency=USD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&srsltid=AfmBOoqZj0QkfjthbjOWND8s8ESTHtYw2Rlm6tU7Z_-3KpandxivtJfKHV4) (just a web search, I'm not affiliated)